# Add domain to ejabberd without server restart

Tags: xmpp, elixir, ejabberd, phoenix-framework

I would like to use multiple domains on a single ejabberd XMPP server, but have the ability to add a domain through the phoenix framework using elixir without any server restarts.

I can add my domains with the `ejabberd.yml` config file as such.

```
..
hosts:
  -  "mydomain1"
  -  "mydomain2"
  -  "mydomain3"
..
```

Ideally if there is a command similar to registering a user, but for creating domains.

```
 :ejabberd_auth.try_register("test2", "localhost", "mypass")
```

I don't know if creating a substantial amount of domains will limit the XMPP server performance wise. So any input or alternatives would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not implemented in ejabberd. You cannot add a domain without a restart at the moment. Moreover, yes, number of domain has an impact of performance as each module and service are started once for each domain.

You would need custom changes / optimisation to use ejabberd in the context of massive virtual hosting.